A HTML file stored as a string in a variable but I want to achieve the value to functions like an HTML file
I got a response and a part of it is like so
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success"
  },
  "data": {
    ...
    "step": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et nisl eget felis hendrerit accumsan eleifend sed enim.</p>\r\n                <ol> \r\n                  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque in purus eget congue. </li>\r\n                  <li>Before...\r\n                    <ul>\r\n                      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>\r\n                      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>\r\n                                        </ul>\r\n                  </li>\r\n                   <li>End...:\r\n                    <ul>\r\n                      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>\r\n                      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>\r\n                                                         </ul>\r\n                  </li>\r\n                </ol>"
  }
}

I have successfully access to the property step to get the HTML file. Then I want to display the HTML file without the HTML tag, so I use bypassSecurityTrustHtml() as follow
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-information',
  imports: [RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
...
})

export class InformationComponent implements OnInit {
sanitizedSteps: SafeHtml;

constructor(
    private data: StudentService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.convertHTML();
  }

 convertHTML(): void {
    this.data.getStudentsById("1").subscribe((res) => {
      this.sanitizedSteps = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res.data.step);
    });
  }
}

The function works as I expected, it strips out all the HTML tags and only returns the texts. However the display looks a bit boring, all of my <li>, <ul>, <ol> tags are not functioning, no bullet points and indentation. The function does however breaks the line for every single tag. But I want those bullet points and indentation to appear. In other words, I want that HTML file to function how it is supposed to be. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.
PS: I am using Angular 17
In case anyone wanna know how the HTML file supposed to look like
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et nisl eget felis hendrerit accumsan eleifend sed enim.</p>              
        <ol>                
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </li>                 
            <li>Before...                   
                <ul>                    
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>                                       
                </ul>                  
            </li>                  
            <li>End...
                <ul>                      
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>                                                     
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ol>

UPDATE: my information.component.html
<mat-tab-group class="tabs flex flex-col gap-2 mt-2 mb-2" [color]="colorToggle.value" [backgroundColor]="backgroundColorToggle.value">
        <mat-tab label="Steps">
            <p [innerHTML]="sanitizedSteps"></p>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


do you binding the innerHTML of a div?: <div [innerHTML]="sanitizedSteps"

I agree  with the comment above because bypassSecurityTrustHtml is not expected to strip the html tags as you stated

include the part of the code where you usesanitizedSteps. also, it could be your css is making it look like that (no bullets etc.)

@Eliseo sorry I forgot that, just updated

@traynor my scss file is empty so i am not sure

Have you tried using the browser developer tools to see what is actually being rendered and what styles are being applied?

@Jack A. yeh I have. I log this.sanitizedSteps and it shows me the HTML file

runs and looks fine for me, bullets and all, can't reproduce..

@traynor :( mine is still no bullet points. I used both Chrome and Opera as browser developer

@nikita try creating a stackblitz demo, see if it shows like that there as well, and include link to it here if yes

The question is not what the server is sending, the question is what the browser is rendering. Most modern browsers provide some form of developer tools that can be used to diagnose issues like you are facing. In Windows, you can usually right-click on a spot on your page and select "Inspect" to see the actual HTML and styles that the browser is using for that part of your page.

@Jack A. Ah i get what you meant. Yes I have but no errors thrown or any warnings unless in my code i log something out
